# Bridging VLAN sub-interfaces

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

How could I bridge together VLAN sub-interfaces?

On my host, I can successfully enslave my `eth0` interface into a bridge. 
I can also successully create and use VLAN sub-interfaces. 
However, I have not suceeded into bridging VLAN sub-interfaces. What am I missing here?

Here is my setup:

[image: setup]

## What I have done

I am using Ubuntu machines (hence, I cannot use e.g. Cisco or OpenWRT-specific commands)

To enslave my eth0 interface:

```
hostA $ sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge
hostA $ sudo ip link set dev br0 up
hostA $ sudo ip link set dev eth0 master br0
hostA $ sudo ip addr del 192.168.0.100/24 dev eth0
hostA $ sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.100/24 dev br0
hostA $ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
# I am still able to ping the Internet
```

To communicate with host B through a sub-interface:

```
hostA $ sudo modprobe 8021q
hostA $ sudo ip link add link eth0 name vlan.10 type vlan id 10
hostA $ sudo ip link set vlan.10 up
hostA $ sudo ip route add 192.168.0.200 dev vlan.10
# I am now able to ping 192.168.0.200, the frame leaving hostA is tagged with VLAN10
```

As soon as I enslave the `vlan.10` sub-interface into `br0`, I am not able to ping 192.168.0.200 anymore. What am I doing wrong?

### My current investigations

I have used tcpdump (actually `termshark` to have instant feedback) to see what is flowing though `eth0` and `vlan.10`.
I am not sure how confident I can be regarding the VLAN Ethernet header shown there, as I have read that it depends on the driver/firmware used by the NIC.

But here is what I have seen there:

- ARP requests for hostB are sent though eth0 wihout a VLAN tag (not expected, but heck)
- ARP reply comes through the vlan.10 interface (and through the eth0 interface with a VLAN Ethernet header) (which means that the request has been received by hostB. Strange but heck)
- `ip neigh` shows that hostB is "registered" on vlan.10 (makes sense since we've just received an ARP response)
- ...but the ping requests are sent without a VLAN tag, though eth0! That's strange because that does not correspond to what the ARP table shows...
- expectedly, I cannot see any ping reply, because I suppose host B never even received the ping request

### Possible alternatives?

- I have been able to connect my hosts by using a different subnet for VLAN10, and having host A perform IP forwarding and NAT (Mmasquerading). However, I'd really like to use only layer2 switching, as it eases the configuration needed on every host.
- I have read bridges can be VLAN-aware. I am not sure this would suit my needs however, because the whole point of doing this is being able to simulate throttled connections between some hosts. Hence, I'd like to attach `netem` qdiscs to specific sub-interfaces. In case I use VLAN-aware bridges, I don't know if I will still be able to use different `tc qdisc` depending on target hosts (unless I could use classful qdiscs and classify packets depending on their source/dest? Not sure. But I'd like to avoid using advanced `tc` commands which I'm not very familiar with).

Comment: To offer an answer on how to use the VLAN sub interface as bridge port, I would first need to understand the experiment. Currently I don't see the point of this experiment: is that linking tagged and untagged traffic together? Also the VLAN-capable switch appears to not do complete isolation considering untagged vlan id 1 (default) appears to have still been bridged toward Host B that should be isolated in VLAN 10 when it received the ARP broadcast. Is the goal (beside tc and netem) to isolate Host B from its LAN and its gateway with  Host A used as a filtering tool?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I wanted to disable default VLAN1 on the port of hostB first. It is now done, port of hostB is only part of VLAN10, and I have the same behaviour. That is slightly different however. Now I do not receive any ARP reply at all. Even ARP requests for the upstream router towards Internet (sent wihtout any VLAN tag) receive no answers.

Comment: Is the goal (beside tc and netem) to isolate Host B from its LAN and its gateway with Host A used as a filtering tool?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. My goal is to have all traffic to (and from) hostB flowing to hostA, so that I can apply traffic shaping on hostA with Linux tc/qdisc tools. Logically, this means having hostA "between" the Internet and hostB. Having VLANs is merely a way to enforce that logical network setup, given the hardware that I currently have.